# TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write upload the file in Google Colaboratory and I'm going to write the code as below.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

But I am getting the below error to run the code in browser.

> MessageError: TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined

Please help me solve the issue.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I just tried the code snippet:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

and everything worked as I'd expect.

A typical cause of the error you observe is using an unsupported browser or a browser extension. Try disabling extensions. Or, if you are using a browser other than Firefox, Safari, or Chrome, try one of these.

Comment: This is not an answer and the problem remains with better answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420759/upload-local-files-using-google-colab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760475/not-able-to-upload-local-files-in-google-collaboratory).

Comment: This should not be considered as the accepted answer

Comment: Could be possible to quit the "accepted answer" badge? I think it is obvious this isn't an answer neither contributes with useful information to the problem.

Answer (score 33):

Well, if running on Brave Browser, i can confirm that **turning down the shields** will do the job.

Comment: Same for Firefox.

Answer (score 20):

Navigate to chrome://settings/content/cookies and turn off "block third-party cookies".
It works for me!

Comment: Clicking on the eye on the right side of the url input box, then "Impossible to access site?", and finally on enable cookies, will do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same problem in google colaboratory as I am using it in incognito mode.

[image: third-party cookies blocked]

You have to allow cookies.

- click the third-party blocking icon
- click Site not working?
- Allow cookies

[image: third-party cookies unblocked]

Here is a sample code that you can check for file uploading. First, mount the drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then use this for uploading files from your local file system.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for filename in uploaded.keys():
    print(uploaded[filename])
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to mount Drive? `files.upload` should work independently from that.

Answer (score 3):

In order to upload the file "YOURFILE.csv" in your directory 'YOURDIRECTORY', You can upload the directory into google drive, and do the following.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content')
```

Then if you see the content of your current directory, you see the "My Drive" which is your google drive and now you can have access to the files saved in your google drive.
!ls command shows you the current directory content.

Now you can import your file into the current colab:

```
your_data = pd.read_csv("./My Drive/YOURDIRECTORY/YOURFILE.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is blocked third-party cookies.

What you can do is,
Navigate to `chrome://settings/cookies`

In the below you will see a section called, `Sites that can always use cookies`

Click on `Add` and add `[*.]googleusercontent.com`

[image]

Now it works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as yours when running the code in Colaboratory in Brave Browser. However, after switching to Google Chrome, it ran just fine. So check the browser you're running in and try another one (I tried Microsoft Edge and it didn't work, btw)

Comment: I can confirm this. I was also using Brave and after I switched to Chrome everything seemed to run smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is being caused due to two things: 1.file.upload() opens up a widget. passing it to the variable somehow is not waiting for the file to be loaded. Its returning - 'MessageError: TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined';2. the other is - this functionality seems to be working for only google chrome as of now else, it will require quite adjusting cookies as suggested in other answers. It is very time consuming unless you have done something like this before.

instead use:

> files.upload()

once the files are upload, say like 'train.csv'. It can be loaded as

> import pandas as pd
>   train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

Comment: At least for me this doesn't work on Brave Browser. I wrote `files.upload` instead of use it inside a variable, and it returns the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you are using Microsoft Edge as a browser go to the following page "edge://settings/privacy" and use the normal mode for tracking protection.
This should solve the problem of accessing the files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. It fails when called from inside a function. The code that fails is here

```
from google.colab import files

def f(fname):
    x = files.upload()
    return x[fname]
f('hello')
```

It works fine when I call files.upload() directly(top-level). It only fails when called from inside a function

Comment: I disagree. It works (now) even in a function in an external module or in a lambda function. If it doesn't work then it depends on other details and it is the same directly in the cell. (or can you confirm the difference now?)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem a minute ago and, although I was not able to catch the error, there is an **alternative** to the file uploading method you are using.

You can just upload your file in Colab by clicking the folder icon at the notebook's **sidebar** and then clicking the upload button.

To load your file into a cell, for example a csv file, you can just write (if you are using pandas):

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to/my_file.csv')
```

this should be browser agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an ad blocker, or possibly an ad-blocking site such as **Brave browser**, or something that blocks cross-site cookies!

If that is the case, try to disable that and it will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The alternate solution would be:

1. Mount your google drive
2. Save your folder from your location machine in google drive
3. Then from the drive copy the path of the file which you need to read

```py
df = pd.read_csv("paste the path you copied here")
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting google chrome, or if that doesn't work, try restarting your computer, that tends to fix any local library issues that my be there.

Answer (score 0):

go to browser settings --> search cookies --> Cookies and other site data

[image]

[image]

Click on allow all cookies then refresh it.
I didn't change any code and I am able to upload the file after the browser changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on Chromium. I switched to Firefox and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already got your answer. On top of that if you are using chrome's incognito mode, there are chances of getting this type error. Try with normal chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

in Brave Browser, follow these instructions:

go to

Settings → Shields, and
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Allow all cookies to fix this error message.

Steps to `fix /typeerror-cannot-read-property-uploadfiles-of-undefined-in-google-colaboratory`

```
Settings->Privacy and security->Cookies and other site data->Allow all cookies(select it)
```

[image: brave settings]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same thing randomly after resetting my session and trying to run all the cells. I had forgotten about a `%%capture` statement at the top of the cell which seemed to cause problems. Removing that worked for me.