# Upload local files using Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Trying to upload local files using Google Collaboratory this way:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

I get the following error:

> Upload widget is only available when the cell has been executed in the current browser session. Please rerun this cell to enable.

I rerun the cell but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It sounds like **third-party cookies** may be disabled in your browser, see https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/17.

The setting is under chrome://settings/content/cookies.

Comment: I was using Firefox with third-party cookies enabled and it was not working but on Chrome works without any problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I was using Firefox too, hitting the shield on the address bar I could turn off 'enhanced tracking protection' and that worked

Answer (score 13):

You can whitelist the following cookies in Chrome:

```
https://[*.]googleusercontent.com:443
```

Comment: Thankyou for providing the specific info lacking in the other answers.  (If not much explanation).  This allows me to get colab working without enabling noxious google ad tracking, etc.

Comment: This fixed it for me in Chrome. To provide further information: you need to follow the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB) to "Allow or block cookies for a specific site" and add the above string.

Answer (score 3):

That text after upload button is very universal:

> **[ Choose Files ]**   Upload widget is only available when the cell has been executed in the current browser session. Please rerun this cell to enable.

It is a text prepared for the case that you or other person will open the shared notebook from a browser in another computer or window. It remains displayed also if the upload widget is blocked due to some security or privacy protection. A significant error message box have been usually displayed before.

If you have run the cell recently from the same window then it is useless to rerun  it if no setting have been fixed between.

**tl;dr)** File upload requires to enable third party cookies in Chrome (the answer above - Chrome settings / Conntent settings / Block third-party cookies and site data - uncheck). In Firefox is [no solution known currently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777857/448474).

---

**Chrome or new Firefox**
If you have **disabled third-party cookies** you have seen this message box (It was displayed only once when any first output cell was displayed for the first time in the notebook, maybe at startup):

> **Error**
>   Could not access the resources needed to display output.
>   This is probably because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.
>
> <sub>Details... [ **V** unfold to see details ]</sub>

<sub>These details are similar:</sub>

> <sup>**Chrome**: NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The user denied permission to use Service Worker</sup>
>   <sup>**Firefox**:  SecurityError: The operation is insecure.</sup>

They expect that you remember it when you see much later a traceback with this internal [error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760475/not-able-to-upload-local-files-in-google-collaboratory). The traceback with `MessageError` is everytimes the same because it contains a copied error that come through pipe from javascript.

> <sup>**Chrome**: MessageError: TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined</sup>
>   <sup>**Firefox**: MessageError: TypeError: google.colab._files is undefined</sup>

**Old Firefox 52 ESR**  (Extended Support Release - still with new security updates)
Colab site never reports currently an intelligible message box for humans in an old Firefox, only a traceback.

---

Colaboratory work relative acceptably also with disabled third-party cookies. I was in a temptation to ignore a message at start of notebook to prefer a standard privacy. I promise that I will never disable them if I want to easily upload a file or to cooperate together with someone other or dislike a wheel icon that remains sometimes rotating busy endless while nothing is running actually :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, so I restarted the Kernel and refreshed the page and the issue was gone. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> I Gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59949460/6066954), but will copy it here anyway, just
>   because this question has reached far more users and could help far
>   more people:

I was having the same problem a minute ago and, although I was not able to catch the error, there is an **alternative** to the file uploading method you are using.

You can just upload your file in Colab by clicking the folder icon at the notebook's **sidebar** and then clicking the upload button.

To load your file into a cell, for example a csv file, you can just write (if you are using pandas):

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to/my_file.csv')
```

this should be browser agnostic.

Comment: Yes, and if you would like to know the path of the file uploaded just double click on it to open it on the right panel, then on the three dots menu-->copy path. No need to change cookies/whitelist for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome try this:

1. Go to chrome://settings/content/cookies
2. Turn off-> Block third-party cookies

This one worked for me