# How can I download a pandas Dataframe in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have been stuck on how to download a pandas DataFrame into my local disk (or onto Google Drive) after creating it in Google Colab. I have tried converting it to bytes, a string (using pd.to_string), a dict (pd.to_dict), but nothing seems to work.

Additionally, I've looked at using the drive.CreateFile method as explained in the intro Colab Code and as specified here: [How to download file created in Colaboratory workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774285/how-to-download-file-created-in-colaboratory-workspace), but I'm not sure how to apply this to pandas.

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: There is an excellent help on colab web site: snippet.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
from google.colab import files

df.to_csv('df.csv')
files.download('df.csv')
```

Comment: As a side note, this might fail on some browsers (works fine on Chrome, but e.g. fails on Firefox Quantum with a `MessageError: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` in which otherwise other colab functionality works fine).

Answer (score 1):

For google colab, i recommend use Pydrive.
Your answer can be found in here
[How to download file created in Colaboratory workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774285/how-to-download-file-created-in-colaboratory-workspace/48774782#48774782)

edit: just change filename.csv to filename.zip or filename.blabla in lines

```
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'filename.csv'})
uploaded.SetContentFile('filename.csv')
```

why? because this line

```
uploaded.SetContentFile('filename.csv')
```

auto set format for you content file, so you don't need to converter it to String or Byte.