# Unable to download .h5 weights file trained on Google Colab (approx 500 mb in size)

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have re-trained a VGG model on google colab.

However when I try to save the model using the below code it throws the following error:

Code:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('vgg_retrained_colab_24epochs_loss_0_47_accuracy_76_88.h5')
```

Error report:
[error report link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEd6w.png)

how can I overcome this? The same code works for smaller files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download file created in Colaboratory workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774285/how-to-download-file-created-in-colaboratory-workspace)

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48774782/5544055

> just change "file_name.csv" to
>   "file_vgg_retrained_colab_24epochs_loss_0_47_accuracy_76_88.h5"

Comment: Thanks @ Mohammed. This seems to be the right way of handling larger files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late now. However, may this answer help someone else at least. I faced a similar problem with checkpoint file, you can find the solution that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49327933/5350646)

Comment: upvoted the answer but more helpful if you could include some steps of achieving it. In this case MJ has outlined it and I will use that. Thanks a ton though.