# Failed to download .ckpt weights from Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I've trained a Tensorflow model on Google Colab, and saved that model in ".ckpt" format.
I want to download the model so I tried to do this:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('/content/model.ckpt.index')
files.download('/content/model.ckpt.meta')
files.download('/content/model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001')
```

I was able to get meta and index files. However, data file is giving me the following error:

> "MessageError: Error: Failed to download: Service Worker Response
>   Error"

Could anybody tell me how should I solve this problem.

Comment: I had the same issue and I am still unsure why (maybe filesize ?). But a possible workaround is to use github to commit your files and then clone to your local machine.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @AnkurAnkan Yes, actually the file size was the problem, I tried to split it into smaller pieces and I was able to download them. Your solution worked for me too and it's much more easier.

Comment: @CraigCitro I am using Chrome and I tried Firefox too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Colab doesn't allow downloading files of large sizes (not sure about the exact limit). Possible solutions could be to either split the file into smaller files or can use github to push your files and then download to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with a 17 Mb graph file using the same command syntax with no error.  Perhaps a transient problem on Google's servers?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to rename the file before download.
I had a file named

`26.9766_0.5779_150-Adam-mean_absolute_error#3#C-8-1-....-RL#training-set-6x6.04.hdf5`

and renamed it to

`model.hdf5`

before download, then it worked. Maybe the '-' in the filename caused the error in my case.