# Download from Google Colab in a scheduled way

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

I'm training a very resourceful CycleGAN.

As the training at night, it happens that the system makes a wipe of the virtual machine and I lose all the checkpoints of my training phases.

I would like to insert a control, in which for example every 100 epochs, the checkpoints are downloaded to my hard disk, so that I can reload them and restart the training.

Is it possible to download files in a programmed way on Colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variants of this question have been asked several times, and the consensus seems to be to transfer results into one's google drive. I do something like what is described here -- it works well for me.

[How to download file created in Colaboratory workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774285/how-to-download-file-created-in-colaboratory-workspace)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.