# How to download an image from the internet using google colab jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, image, download, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I need to download an image using a url. I managed to obtain the urls of the images I need to download, but now I'm lost on how to download it to my local computer. I'm using google colab/ jupyter. Thank you!
here's my code so far:

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import urllib.request

#use Globe API to get data

#input userid - plan: have program read userids from csv or excel file
userid = xxxxxxxx

#use Globe API to get data
source = requests.get('https://api.globe.gov/search/v1/measurement/protocol/measureddate/userid/?protocols=land_covers&startdate=2020-05-04&enddate=2020-07-16&userid=' + str(userid) +'&geojson=FALSE&sample=FALSE').text
#set up BeautifulSoup4
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#Isolate the Json data and put it into a string called "paragraph"
body = soup.find('body')
paragraph = body.p.text

#load the string into a python object
data = json.loads(paragraph)

#pick out the needed information and store them
for landcover in data['results']:
  siteId = landcover['siteId']
  measuredDate = landcover['measuredDate']
  latitude = landcover['latitude']
  longitude = landcover['longitude']
  protocol = landcover['protocol']
  DownURL = landcover['data']['landcoversDownwardPhotoUrl']
  #Here is where I want to download the url contained in 'DownURL'
```

Comment: Does this help some? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774285/how-to-download-file-created-in-colaboratory-workspace

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I've already tried using that function, but it doesn't work because I want to download an image using its url, which is different from downloading a file created in colab. I'm still a beginner so I may be misunderstanding something

Comment: Yup, the only way you’ll be able to do this is by saving the file in colab and then using that function. Otherwise I would just run the code locally instead of in colab to download it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! What would saving the image in colab look like? What are the functions?

Comment: Should be something like imwrite, but I would search around for a function to save an image that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from google.colab import files as FILE
import os

img_data = requests.get(DownURL).content
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)

FILE.download('image_name.jpg')
os.remove('image_name.jpg') # to save up space
```

You can call a random function in case you do not wish to set an image name or a counter variable which keeps increments at each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works, but for some reason, I am missing half of the images. Is it because they were downloaded all at once?

Comment: It will be better if you trace the program. You can create a log which stores the URLs fetched, number of images fetched and number of downloaded images. Wherever you find the mismatch, try to trace every step.   Also, you can make sure of try except block so that u can catch exceptions incase you are missing out any image. (Note: I'm assuming you are processing one by one in sequential manner and not all URLs first, then images and then download)