# Unable to upload local files using Google Colab

Tags: google-chrome, google-colaboratory

I am getting error when trying to upload file to Google Colab.

```
Upload widget is only available when the cell has been executed in the current browser session.
Please rerun this cell to enable.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-1bbed4ac709e> in <module>()
     62 from keras.preprocessing import image
     63 
---> 64 uploaded = files.upload()
     65 
     66 for fn in uploaded.keys():
```

**My Browser:**  Google Chrome, Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit) (on Windows 10)

I found two questions asked previously. See below. However, neither of the solutions worked for me.

- https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/17
- [Upload local files using Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420759/upload-local-files-using-google-colab)

Here's the image of my Chrome settings:
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you try to upload it using the GUI? To do this, you can go to the "Files" tab on the left, and click the "Upload to session storage" button at the top.

Comment: Yes, I was able to successfully upload.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I was trying to execute bunch of scripts in same cell in Colab. When it came to the files.upload(), it was causing the issue. I moved that segment into another cell and executed it. It worked fine. Looks like Colab does not like it when you do this.

Here's code snippet I was referring to:

```
# RUNNING THE MODEL
print('RUNNING THE MODEL')
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
 
  # predicting images
  path = '/content/' + fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(300, 300))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(classes[0])
  if classes[0]>0.5:
    print(fn + " is a human")
  else:
    print(fn + " is a horse")
```