# Not able to upload local files in google colab

Tags: python, file-upload, google-colaboratory

I am trying to upload a word2vec file in Google Colaboratory from local system and use it further in the in code.

This is the code that I used.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Everytime I execute it, it is showing the following error.

> Upload widget is only available when the cell has been executed in the current browser session. Please rerun this cell to enable

```
 MessageError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-292f82be1b7a> in <module>()  

      1 from google.colab import files
      2 
----> 3 uploaded = files.upload()`
      4 
      5 for fn in uploaded.keys():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/files.py in upload() 

     59   result = output.eval_js(
     60       'google.colab._files._uploadFiles("{input_id}", "{output_id}")'.format(
---> 61           input_id=input_id, output_id=output_id))
     62   files = collections.defaultdict(six.binary_type)
     63 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py in 
eval_js(script, ignore_result)

     37   if ignore_result:
     38     return
---> 39   return _message.read_reply_from_input(request_id)
     40 
     41 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in 
read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)

     84         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
     85       if 'error' in reply:
---> 86         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
     87       return reply.get('data', None)
     88 

MessageError: TypeError: google.colab._files is undefined
```

Why is this happening? What should I do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This issue is currently being investigated for Firefox at: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/51.

As a temporary workaround is there recommended to upload files by Chrome.

Comment: A [solution for Chrome is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427329/448474) - to enable third-party cookies if they are disabled and you want it. Upload from a shared cell in Firefox to a private virtual machine is hard as you wrote above because the security context is complicated and they tailored it first for Chrome.

Comment: solution from @mindshoot  is perfect for Firefox guys, who do not use Chrome at all. It is simple and perfect.

Comment: Even after more than four years ago, file upload on GoogleColab doesn't work properly on Firefox :S.

Answer (score 15):

Switching off Enhanced Protection for the site in Firefox, which is accessible via the little "security shield" to the left of the URL, did the trick perfectly for me...

Comment: You are a gem! It did the job smoothly and perfectly. I was terrified looking at top answers saying this is the problem with Firefox but they have a solution for Chrome. I don't know the chrome in years, I am a Firefox guy for years now. You just nailed it with this simple solution. I just turned it off and reran the cell. Bingo

Answer (score 3):

Well for me, I first tried to factory reset the runtime but it didn't work

Then i just restarted the runtime and refreshed the page, it then worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using brave browser, set  all cookies allowed in brave shields.

Comment: It worked for me as I use brave, also it could work if you set - "All cookies allowed" in your browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when my computer was simply overloaded. It was unable to manage colab and my other tabs being open. Closing colab and the other tabs in the taskmanager before trying again solved the problem for me.